# How to perform off-line live upgrade?

Tags: opensuse, upgrade

openSUSE supports for some time online live upgrade. However I see two issues here:

- minor -- I already have DVD downloaded and burned
- major -- until now my eth0 card is not **oficially** supported, so on every upgrade it is disabled, and later I have to install drivers for it. I am afraid it might be the case with live upgrade as well -- i.e. upgrader would "upgrade" the driver for eth0, disabling it, and eventually breaking entire upgrade process

So I am wondering if I could treat DVD as repository and point it for zypper to perform live upgrade "downloading" packages from the disc? Is it possible? How to do it?

*I cannot run DVD and perform upgrade from there, because installer from the disc has hard time recognizing my LVM partitions, in short -- it does not recognize them. So I though why not try it from running system with fully working partitions.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, zypper's man page has two example uris of doing just that.

`man 8 zypper`

```
CD or DVD drive
       Optionally with devices list for probing.

       cd:///
       dvd:/subdir?devices=/dev/sr0,/dev/sr1
```

You can add them repo zypper's `addrepo` command.

`zypper ar dvd:/?devices=/dev/sr0`

For more information refer to http://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:Libzypp_URIs

Comment: Thank you. So despite the info about live-upgrade it can be configured that way (download DVD and use it as repo) that it has all advantages without any drawbacks.